# internet connection not working with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dns

I have been facing this issue for past few week.

My computer is connected with wired internet, with proper network configuration. (have tried both DHCP & Manual).

it fails to connect to every other webpage i am surfing. once i disconnect-&- connect-again, it start working for seconds.

and then problem repeats always.

I wrongly assumed that the update caused this fault & troubleshooting make it worse. so i made a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04. (completly wiped the partition and installed again)

To my great surprise the same problem occurs instantly on this newly installed ubuntu machine.

this time i do not want to mess-up the network settings so i raised this new question here.

1. I can ping my network anytime.
2. i can ping my DNS IP anytime.
3. I can ping always 8.8.8.8 and other globle DNS
4. i can ping www.google.com through IP address but not directly
5. replacing my DNS with 8.8.8.8 do not solve this problem.

[Connection Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miLvH.png)

```
linux@linux:~$ ping 14.139.5.5
PING 14.139.5.5 (14.139.5.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 14.139.5.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=70.4 ms
64 bytes from 14.139.5.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=62.0 ms
64 bytes from 14.139.5.5: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=68.0 ms
64 bytes from 14.139.5.5: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=61.5 ms
64 bytes from 14.139.5.5: icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=63.4 ms
64 bytes from 14.139.5.5: icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=70.0 ms
^C
--- 14.139.5.5 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 61.551/65.944/70.427/3.715 ms
linux@linux:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=159 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=98.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=98.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=125 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=45 time=155 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=45 time=172 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=45 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=45 time=162 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 98.400/134.047/172.133/29.693 ms
linux@linux:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
linux@linux:~$ ping 216.58.211.142
PING 216.58.211.142 (216.58.211.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.211.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=408 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.211.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=412 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.211.142: icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=436 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.211.142: icmp_seq=4 ttl=42 time=407 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.211.142: icmp_seq=5 ttl=42 time=410 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.211.142: icmp_seq=6 ttl=42 time=407 ms
^C
--- 216.58.211.142 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 407.414/413.890/436.571/10.346 ms
linux@linux:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

I can ping any website by its IP address but can not ping or open it in browser that's the issue.

I am not alone who is facing this issue with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS. 
this forum is full with all similar kind of problem (some are solved) but i do not find any solution which work for me.

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command: `sudo resolvconf -u` ?

Comment: - reboot your modem ? - reboot your router ? - reinstall package network-manager ?

Answer (score 0):

For a start - I'd try to eliminate any user configuration issues as a cause.

I'd start by booting from a live Ubuntu 16.04 USB/CD, and starting a live session, and connecting to the network and playing around for a bit.

You can snag a 16.04 live image from here:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Personally, I'd use unetbootin to burn that image to a USB stick and boot from that.

If this results in everything working - maybe think back to configuration changes you may have made?

Comment: As mentioned in question,I have raised this query just after fresh install of ubuntu 16.04. the cause of re-install is same network issue. but it didn't solve it.

Comment: @courser You need to start considering the possibility of hardware failure.

Comment: The desktop PC is dual boot, internet is perfectly working on windows 10 OS. One more thing, same kind of problem i have been facing in another laptop. i have discontinued ubuntu usage in that until i find solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yours and it had been solved.
The solution is here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/974609/757574